# Find the roots of a polynomial with modulus coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

I am asked to prove:

[image]

I was sick during the week where my proffesor went over this and I cannot understand his notes.

My current approach is to find the roots over the normal polynomial (in this case 4 and 5) and look for the elements that can be generated with their powers (i.e $4^2 = 16 \equiv_6 4$, $4^3=64 \equiv_6 4$, $5^2 = 25 \equiv_6 1$, $5^3 = 125 \equiv_6 5$)...

And try to find some general pattern. However (1-5=-4 $\equiv_6 2$) is not a root. So it seems I am completely off.

Comment: One good solid method is to just try all the values.  In both cases here, that only takes a few seconds.  Not sure I follow your reasoning as to all the squares.

Comment: Worth noting:  $7$ is quite different from $6$ here.  For $7$, as it is a prime, the product of two integers is divisible by $7$ iff at least one of the integers is.  This makes your task a lot easier.

Comment: Is there not a "general method" other than brute forcing every single possibility?

Comment: Well, for primes I told you the method in my comment.  For composite numbers you can certainly work with prime factors and build from there, but, honestly, those methods don't make a lot of sense for $6$.

Comment: Use Chinese remainder theorem. $\Bbb Z/6 = \Bbb Z/2 \oplus \Bbb Z/3$, so your equation is equivalent to system "$x(x+1) = 0$ mod 2, $(x+2)(x+1)$ mod 3". As $\Bbb Z/2$ and $\Bbb Z/3$ are fields, solving this is pretty easy task.

Comment: @lulu Your second comment is very important! In fact, I ad hoc wanted to apply the "easy" solution in the case $\mathbb Z_6$ , which is of course wrong.